# Formato de fecha en Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Tengo un párrafo al que deseo concatenar una fecha pero en este formato "01 de Enero de 2019". El fecha ya tiene su formato de fecha correspondiente

Ejemplo:

```
"Este es el párrafo" & @Fecha
```

Resultado actual:

```
"Este es el párrafo 01/01/2019"
```

Resultado deseado:

```
"Este es el párrafo 01 de Enero de 2019"
```

Comment: Has probado a darle al botón derecho sobre @fecha y en formato tienes todas las opciones de formato

Comment: Si ya lo he hecho y me da el resultado de la fecha a como deseo, pero ése formato lo deseo concatenar con un párrafo manteniendo el mismo formato de fecha y es ahí donde no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: Puedes añadir un objeto texto y poner dentro "esto es  el párrafo " y  dentro de ese  objeto añadir el campo fecha, de modo que el campo queda dentro, no al lado, y botón derecho y formato

Comment: Al final lo solucioné construyendo la fecha a como deseaba les dejo el código por si alguien lo puede llegar a usar "Este es el párrafo " & ToText(Day ({@Fecha}), 0,'') & " días del mes de " & MonthName(Month ({@Fecha})) & " del año " & ToText(Year({@Fecha}),0,'')